# How to get the available themes for a given LookAndFeel?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I can get the LookAndFeel list by

```
UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] lafInfo = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
```

But how can I get the list of themes for e.g. the "Metal" LookAndFeel ?
I really do not want to hardcode "DefaultMetal", "Ocean",  and "Test".

Answer (score 0):

You on the right way, you must iterate LaFs and choose what you want.

`l.getName()` return theme name

Example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LookAndFeelInfo[] installedLookAndFeels = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
    for(LookAndFeelInfo l : installedLookAndFeels){
        System.out.println(l.getName());
        if(l.getName().equals("Metal")){
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(l.getClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: you can try to find all subclasses of MetalTheme with reflection, but I think it is bad choice.

Comment: Yes, but after that, how do I get the list of the themes supported by Metal ? "Themes" does not mean "LAF's". It means something like "Color schemes": "Metal" supports "DefaultMetal", "Ocean", and "Test". They are set by e.g. MetalLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(new OceanTheme());

Comment: I think you can't do somithing like that `MetalLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(new OceanTheme());` . but you can set LaF and change it color scheme by next way `UIManager.put("nimbusBase", new Color(...));
UIManager.put("nimbusBlueGrey", new Color(...));` and others color scheme keys. I mean you cant list all themes

Comment: I found MetalLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(new OceanTheme()); in the oracle swing tutorial about LAF's. But they don't say how to enumerate the available themes. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Comment: I know but if you look at `NimbusLookAndFeel` it hasn't the same method. I think it depends on implementation of them. And you can set scheme only manual way, without automated search.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. As shown in [How to Set Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#themes) tutorial there's no way to get an available themes list. If you take a look to [MetalLookAndFeel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalLookAndFeel.html) class there are several static methods but nothing like:

```
public static MetalTheme[] getAvailableThemes(){...}
```

I think it would be a very useful feature. Anyway your best chance is harcoding the names since the only thing you can certainly do to determine if a class is a theme for Metal look and feel is asking if it's an instance of [MetalTheme](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalTheme.html) but that gives you almost nothing to achieve your target.

Comment: Well, that's bad news... My goal was to create a tab in my settings dialog with two ComboBoxes. The user selects a L&F in the first box and then the second box is refreshed and offers a choice of themes supported by the chosen L&F. I have seen this in many tools. Do you think they hardcoded the theme select box ?

Comment: Indeed it is, sorry about that :( They could hardcode the themes or well use reflection. But the last one is very expensive and is not a very good practice because implies iterate over the whole classpath looking for a class that extends from a class (or implements an interface). I think in your case it would be better hardcode the class (we are talking about 3 classes). @MarkusN.